# Filtering animals using wpf radiobuttons

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, radio-button, mvp

I am playing with a sample WPF application that is tiered in a Model-View-Presenter manner. The Model is a collection of Animals which is displayed in a view via binding to properties in a presenter class. The XAML has an items control that displays all the animals in a model.

The model class has a boolean attribute called 'IsMammal'. I want to introduce a filter in the XAML in the form of a radio button group that filters the collection of animals based on the 'IsMammal' attribute. Selection of the radiobutton 'Mammals' updates the items control with all the Animals that have the 'IsMammal' value set to true and when the value is toggled to 'Non-Mammals', the display is updated with all animals that have that particular boolean set to false. The logic to do the filtering is extremely simple. What is troubling me is the placement of the logic. I don't want any logic embedded in the *.xaml.cs. I want the toggling of the radiobutton to trigger a logic in the presenter that tapers my animal collection to be rebound to the display.

Some guidance here will be extremely appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I think that is not possible with no code behind in neat way. Does is really a problem to have 6 lines of code behind?

Comment: @lukas - It will be great if you could post the six lines of code that you will use in the 'code behind' to achieve this functionality?

Comment: http://www.galasoft-lb.ch/mydotnet/articles/article-2007081301.aspx something like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you do the following in your Presenter:

=>  Create a ListCollectionView field.  Set it to be equal to the "Default Collection View" of your collection, and use it as the ItemsSource for the list control.  Something like:

```
    public class Presenter()
    {
        private ListCollectionView lcv;

        public Presenter()
        {
            this.lcv = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(animalsCollection);
            listControl.ItemsSource = this.lcv;
        }
    }
```

=>  In the handler/logic for the RadioButton's corresponding event, filter the ListCollectionView.  Something like:

```
void OnCheckedChanged()
{
     bool showMammals = radioButton.IsChecked;
     this.lcv.Filter = new Predicate((p) => (p as Animal).IsMammal == showMammals);
     this.lcv.Refresh();
}
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

While doing this is possible using MVP, using MVVM should be a better choice, IMHO (and as mentioned by the other answer).  To help you out, I wrote a sample that implements your requirements via MVVM.  See below:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

            <RadioButton x:Name="rb1" GroupName="MyGroup" Content="IsMammal = true" Checked="rb1_Checked"/>
            <RadioButton x:Name="rb2" GroupName="MyGroup" Content="IsMammal = false" Checked="rb2_Checked"/>

            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AnimalsCollectionView}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void rb1_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            (this.DataContext as ViewModel).UpdateFilter(true);
        }

        private void rb2_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            (this.DataContext as ViewModel).UpdateFilter(false);
        }
    }

    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Animal> animals = new ObservableCollection<Animal>();
        private ListCollectionView animalsCollectionView;

        public ListCollectionView AnimalsCollectionView
        {
            get { return this.animalsCollectionView; }
        }

        public void UpdateFilter(bool showMammals)
        {
            this.animalsCollectionView.Filter = new Predicate<object>((p) => (p as Animal).IsMammal == showMammals);
            this.animalsCollectionView.Refresh();
        }

        public ViewModel()
        { 
            this.animals.Add(new Animal() { Name = "Dog", IsMammal = true });
            this.animals.Add(new Animal() { Name = "Cat", IsMammal = true });
            this.animals.Add(new Animal() { Name = "Bird", IsMammal = false });

            this.animalsCollectionView = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.animals);

        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public class Animal : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return this.name; }
            set
            {
                this.name = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }

        private bool isMammal;
        public bool IsMammal
        {
            get { return this.isMammal; }
            set
            {
                this.isMammal = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("IsMammal");
            }
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am a little confused by the 'listControl.ItemsSource = this.lcv'. Does this mean that the Presenter class needs to be aware of the controls that are present on the view? Also for the 'OnCheckedChanged()' you mentioned how it is the RadioButton's corresponding event, can you elaborate in your example to show how the OnCheckedChange which will be defined in the presenter, is invoked by the RadioButton's on the XAML.

Comment: It really depends on your Presenter implementation.  I was assuming that your Presenter object has a reference to the View, hence my example above.  I guess the key ideas I'm trying to say are:  1) Use a ListCollectionView, and 2)  Have something in the Presenter that will update the ListCollectionView's filter when the RadioButton's values get updated.

Answer (score 1):

I came from an MVP background before learning WPF and I have come to find that adapting the MVP pattern to WPF is a difficult exercise at best. The "proper" (read, least frustrating) approach is to utilize the Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) pattern, which makes heavy use of the databinding features of WPF to minimize the amount of code that ends up the view-behind file.

In the simplest case, you would end up with two properties on your ViewModel:

- bool FilterMammals
- ObservableCollection MammalsToDisplay

In the XAML, You would bind the first to your radio button group and the second to the ItemsSource of the ListBox. The WPF databinding framework will call your property setter whenever the radiobutton group value changes, and in here you can filter and then update the list of items.

I'm not sure what your familiarity with MVVM is, so I'll stop here. Let me know if more detail would help :).

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out MVVM. Details will definitely help and also it will be great to get some insight into why this approach(creating two additional properties in the Presenter and binding it to the XAML) would not work for MVP.

Comment: It's not that it wouldn't work for MVP, it's that creating and binding properties is fundamentally not MVP at that point (although arguably most of the UI presentation patterns overlap with each other in some fashion). You can think of MVVM as removing the "presenting" responsibility from the Presenter and letting WPF's databinding capabilities handle that. This leaves the cold, hard data behind which is essentially a model built specifically for your view, hence "View-Model". Make sense?